# Laravel Vue.js - how to use blade suntax in axios URL

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-blade

In my Laravel + Vue.js SPA ( Single Page Application ), I am using `axios` as the HTTP client to make the `POST` request. In Vue component namely `Register.vue`, I have :

```
axios.post('@{{ route("register") }}',
                    this.name, // the data to post
                    { headers: {
                            'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        }
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.result = response.data.bpi
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                        this.errored = true
                    });
```

But the Firfox browser console shows 404 error when the request is made and the URL to which `axios` tries to make the request shows to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/@%7B%7B%20route(%22register%22)%20%7D%7D` from the network tab.

How can I use the `route('register')` as the URL in `axios` ajax request ?

**EDIT:**

In case you are curious to know the architecture of the app, I'll try to elaborate it below :

The `app.js` file has :

```
window.axios = require('axios');
import router from './router';
import App from '../components/App.vue';

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,

  mount(){

    console.log("Root instance mounted ");
  }
});
```

The `router.js` file has :

```
import Register from '../components/Register.vue';
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/register', component: Register, name: 'register' }
  ],
```

The `web.php` has :

```
Auth::routes();// it contains login, register etc routes
```

My `App.vue`  has :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="toolbar">
         My Toolbar  
        </div>
        <router-view></router-view>

    </div>
</template>
```

So when the `/register` URL is hit,  `app.js` loads `App.vue` and according to the path specification in `router.js`, `Register` component in `Register.vue` is rendered in the place of `<register-view></register-view>` in `App.vue` file.  Relevant `axios` ajax part in `Register.vue` has been given before.

**EDIT2:**

Inside `RegisterController`, I went to the `use RegistersUsers` trait thought IDE navigation and made the following change:

```
 public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
   //return view('auth.register'); //discarded this line
        return view('app');
    }
```

Inside `assets/views/app.blade.php`, I have :

```
<body>

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use blade syntax within Vue unless you are writing the Vue code directly in the blade template, which would not be best practice. One thing I have found helpful is to write out all my Laravel API routes in a google docs so they are easier to refer to when referencing them in Vue. I hope that helps!

Comment: ' write out all my Laravel API routes in a google doc ' - how do you use google docs  here  ?

Comment: Just open up a google docs blank page and list out all your Laravel API routes.

Comment: The docs doesn't really serve much purpose does it? You have all this listed in your router files any ways?

Comment: It's simply a matter of preference. They can be cleaner and easier to read when in a google docs. You can do what you prefer!

Comment: Do you mind marking my answer as top please if that helped?

Comment: You will need to call the route statically.

Comment: @L.Fox, no way to call it in Laravel way ?

Comment: Not within VueJs

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this without a `.blade` file. there is no support given for vue components to use laravel routes dynamically. but you could use some third party packages to achieve this something like `Ziggy`

https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy

Comment: the vue component lives inside `app.blade.php`. See 'EDIT2'

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed if you're using blade you could do `{!! route('register') !!}`. but I am assuming according to your code that you're using vue component and calling php `route('register')` with in vue component that wouldn't work. for vue component you can use the above mentioned plugin.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed also try using `{!! route('register') !!}` instead of `{{ route('register') }}`

Answer (score -2):

You can only use blade syntax, if you're in a `.blade` file.

You have to statically set this route or others when calling a API

NOT RECOMMENDED:
Or you can define a js variable in your "master" blade file, which you're then using in the `Register.vue` file.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. That can get cluttered very quickly.

Comment: I totally agree, but it's one way to get around it

Comment: As programmers, we shouldn't be simply looking for "one way to get around it" we should be looking for the best most clean way to write it.